# image editing on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

My intention is to allow my users to build custom lock screens/wallpapers with custom texts and may be other images. Can someone point me to some resources how I can do this in compliance with the Windows Phone 7 SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) provides many example Windows Phone applications. Using one or a combination of these example should put you in a resonable position.

I hope this helps.